# DocuSign REST API: Correcting a document & too many api calls

Tags: docusignapi

**Scenario:**

My application dynamically generates a contract (PDF) on-the-fly through the use of some base language and replacement variables from user data.  That pdf is then sent to the DocuSign REST API with the list of recipients/signers/tabs which handles delivery of the agreement to the various parties.

**Issue:**

At times during the negotiation process for the contract, users may need to make edits to the agreement.  My application has a correction interface where they're able to regenerate the original PDF and then have an action that allows them to update the existing envelope.

To perform these corrections, I'm currently using the following API Calls for a single correction:

1. `getEnvelope` to retrieve the current status and make sure the envelope hasn't been voided, completed, etc.
2. `deleteEnvelopeDocuments` to remove all existing documents.
3. `updateDocuments` to send the base64 encoded document to the envelope.
4. `updateEnvelope` to send the recipients back to the envelope because they're deleted as a result to #2.

These 4 API calls feel like a mistake to me because if any one of them fails for whatever reason, the entire process fails.  In addition, the processing time for the back-and-forth is also a consideration even though I could delegate that to a queue'd background process.

**My Question (I know, finally)**

Is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do? Perhaps I can skip #1 and just catch an exception thrown by DocuSign when attempting to update a completed / voided envelope.  What I'm really interested in knowing is if I can consolidate #2-4 into a single call somehow.  The API doesn't feel super clear on corrections and also doesn't send any notifications when an envelope is updated via the API.

Answer (score 1):

I think this can be done with two API calls instead of four.

You can make a PUT call to replace a document

```
PUT .../envelopes/<envID>/documents/1
```

This API replaces an existing document, there's no need to do 2+3 separately.

This would eliminate the need to do #4 as well, because the tabs (not recipients as you stated) are not going to be removed if you don't delete the document but simply update it.

Comment: No, I'm afraid not.  The revisions being made are by the sender, not the recipient.

Comment: let me update my answer, you can do a PUT to replace document.

Comment: This sounds promising.  So my confusion on that method is that looking at the API doc page for that method, the params are accountId/documentId/envelopeid.  I'm using the PHP SDK, I don't see an EnvelopeDefinition to be able to specify the document I'm replacing with.  Do you have a short example of how I can specify the document in the API request?

Comment: https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-php/blob/master/src/EG001EmbeddedSigning.php
This code is to create a new envelope, not update, but the EnvelopeDefinition is the same and so you can use snippets from it and just change to call $envelope_api->updateDocuments() instead of $envelope_api->createEnvelope()

Comment: Interesting.  I had been wondering why I couldn't just replace the document (as you can in the cloud), but my confusion came from the fact that there isn't an EnvelopeDefinition defined in the SDK or even mentioned on the update method page.  Thank you, I'm going to give that a go.  I'll come back and mark this as answered once I get it working.